# SQL Server Overwrite Database from Backup

Tags: sql, database-backups

I'm trying to overwrite our dev database from our live one. I selected the dev database for the "to database" and the backup file for the "from device".

Question: In the "restore as" value in the grid in the options tab, should the live database or dev database be there? By default, it is the file name of the live database.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dev database -- this is the file you will overwrite!!